# How to make CLI / C++ Wrapper of C++ native?

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

This is my native files...

1.) test.h

```
#if !defined (TEST)
#define TEST

namespace ABB
{
    namespace CRLDownload_Native
    {
        class A
        {
            public:
                int x;
                int init();

        };

        class B : public A
        {
            public:
                int abc();
        };
    }
}

#endif
```

2.) test.cpp

```
#include"test.h"

using namespace ABB::CRLDownload_Native;

int A::init()
{
    x = 15;
    return 20;
}

int B::abc()
{
    return x;
}
```

this files are my native code. I want to wrapper it in CLI/C++ project.

---

This below files are CLI/C++ code.

3.) test_cli.h

```
#if!defined (TEST_CLR)
#define TEST_CLR
#include"test.h"

namespace ABB
{
    namespace CRLDownload_CLR
    {
    //  ref class B;
        namespace native = ABB::CRLDownload_Native;
        public ref class A
        {
            public:
                A();
                ~A();
                !A();
                int init();

                native::A * obj1;
        };

        public ref class B : public A
        {
            public:
                B();
                ~B();
                !B();
                int abc();
                native ::B * obj; 
        };
    }
}


#endif
```

4.) test_cli.cpp

```
#include"test_clr.h"

using namespace ABB::CRLDownload_CLR;

A::A()
{
    obj1 = new native :: A;
}
A :: !A()
{

}

A :: ~A()
{

}

int A::init()
{
    return (obj1->init());
}

B::B()
{
    obj = new native ::B;
}
B ::~B()
{

}
B ::!B()
{

}
int B::abc()
{
    return (obj->abc());
}
```

This CLI/C++ library I want access in C#.
so if I create

```
 int ret=-1;
 B Obj;
 ret=obj.init();
 ret=obj.abc();
```

at last ret should be 15 but I am not getting.
can anyone help me?

Comment: `obj = obj1;` in B::abc() makes no sense.  Delete that.  You must implement the destructor and finalizer.

Comment: by mistake I wrote it. I know that..

Comment: Please provide code which compiles. You cannot possibly assign obj1 to obj because they are pointers to different classes. And even if you could, doing that and then invoking obj->abc() is just insane. What do you want to achieve with this rather crippled class hierarchy, and what is your question?

Comment: I have big project... but same situation I facing in it. so simply I created demo for that.. I want to access x anyhow... in C#

Comment: my native library is perfectly working but I did mistake in wrapper only

Comment: demo still doesn't compile - test things first before posting seemingly random code here..

Comment: i complied it.. and there is no single warning

Comment: if u want then i can put screen shot of it

Comment: `B Obj; ret=obj.init();` first you have *O*bj then *o*bj,so doesn't compile

Comment: i was not talking about C# code..

Comment: i was talking about library only

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't return 15 because you have two seperate native A and B objects, and you call init() on one and abc() on the other. Suggestion: use a debugger to step through the code and you'll have noticed immediately.

Easiest solution is to simply not repeat the class hierarchy in the wrapper and provide B only, like:

```
public ref class B
{
public:
  B() : obj( new native::B() ){}
  ~B() { this->!B(); }
  !B() { delete obj; obj = nullptr; }
  int init() { return obj->init(); }
  int abc() { return obj->abc(); }

private:
  native::B* obj; 
};
```

And don't forget to implement destruction or you'll have memory leaks.

Comment: Yes...
I have two derived class... B and C of Base class A.
we can not achieve reusability.. :(

in my actual code 
init() is same for B and C class object.
Run() is different for both B and C class object

Comment: It's really not clear to me what you want to achieve, you should edit your question so it includes pseudocode of what you want the cli wrapper to do.